# Data binding for HTML email

Tags: java, html, string, email

I am having some data in a text file on my computer, and I have an HTML template for emailing purposes. The HTML template consists of a table. I would like to bind my data in the text file to the tables in the template dynamically and then mail it to someone else.

Example:

Data is:

```
A 56 sdsfs
B 12 tfhf
C 21 ttytut
```

This data should go into a table, and then I would mail it to someone else.

What I thought of doing was downloading the whole HTML text, using certain fixed strings as placeholders for where the data would go, and then using a string replace for those to fill in the data. But I would like a more elegant solution to this.

I am using JAVA and Mandrill wrapper for java for sending mails. Please do comment if something is not clear.

Comment: You can templatize your HTML file using some placeholder. You can have a look at `Mustache.js` to get some rough idea about how to proceed.

Comment: @D3V I am looking into it.

Comment: `Mustache` is also available in Java.

Comment: @D3V I think, internally, this also works in a similar manner as I mentioned, that using string replace. Is any other elegant solution possible. Like, in server side I have AJAX fetch something from a text file and fill the elements automatically. This wouldn't work here because I am sending HTML as my mail body.

Comment: Templates are going to work in that way only(more or less optimized). The magic is in the way templates are parsed and kept for swift processing.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a something like [Freemarker](http://freemarker.org/) for this task.

Comment: Looks like an answer to me.

Comment: It provides no implementation and no examples, just a link to a webpage (which can go broken in future).